# auto() in Dataclass like auto() in Enum (Python)

Tags: python, enums, python-dataclasses

Is there a way to do the same code below using Dataclass instead of Enum?

```
from enum import Enum, auto


class State(Enum):
    val_A= auto()
    val_B = auto()
    val_C = auto()
```

The only solution I found is the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class State():
    val_A:str = 'val_A'
    val_B:str = 'val_B'
    val_C:str = 'val_C'
```

thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Descriptors

One approach could be to use a [descriptor class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), defined as below:

```py
class Auto:
    _GLOBAL_STATE = {}

    __slots__ = ('_private_name', )

    # `owner` is the class or type, whereas instance is an object of `owner`
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            return getattr(instance, self._private_name)
        except AttributeError:
            _state = self.__class__._GLOBAL_STATE
            _dflt = _state[owner] = _state.get(owner, 0) + 1
            return _dflt

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._private_name = '_' + name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # use object.__setattr__() instead of setattr() as dataclasses
        # also does, in case of a "frozen" dataclass
        object.__setattr__(instance, self._private_name, value)
```

Usage would be as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class State:
    val_A: int = Auto()
    val_B: int = Auto()
    val_C: int = Auto()


s = State()
print(s)  # State(val_A=1, val_B=2, val_C=3)
assert s.val_B == 2

s = State(val_A=5)
assert s.val_A == 5
assert s.val_C == 3
```

### Optimal Approach

The most performant approach I can think of, would be to replace the default values before `dataclasses` is able to process the class.

Initially this is `O(N)` time, as it would require iterating over all the class members (including dataclass fields) at least once. However, the real benefit is that it replaces the default values for `auto` values, such as `val_A: int = 1`, before the `@dataclass` decorator is able to process the class.

For example, define a metaclass such as one below:

```py
# sentinel value to detect when to replace a field's default
auto = object()


def check_auto(name, bases, cls_dict):
    default = 1

    for name, val in cls_dict.items():
        if val == auto:
            cls_dict[name] = default
            default += 1

    cls = type(name, bases, cls_dict)
    return cls
```

Usage is as below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class State(metaclass=check_auto):
    val_A: int = auto
    val_B: int = auto
    val_C: int = auto


s = State()
print(s)  # State(val_A=1, val_B=2, val_C=3)
assert s.val_B == 2

s = State(val_A=5)
assert s.val_A == 5
assert s.val_C == 3
```